# SSL problem in power BI with bigquery data

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I can't refresh data

```
  ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1120) SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate. ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1120) SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate.
```

Comment: you are basically missing a certificate

Answer (score 0):

Problems can be 2:

- [Add command timeout](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Bigquery-connection-error/td-p/1602196)
- [you may input incorrect host name](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/Problem-connecting-with-Big-Query-from-Power-BI-Desktop-ODBC/idi-p/2403073)

Comment: I found the reason for the error. It was caused by an anti-virus program.

Comment: @VD, post the answer, please

Comment: The whole problem was due to the fact that the Kaspersky anti-virus system did auto-setting of its ssl certificate when trying to connect to the bigquery. I disabled the check for power bi in the antivirus settings.